# Create java.util.Date from C# System.TimeZone

Tags: java, c#, date, datetime, java.util.date

I have a Java service which needs to return date/time information that is formatted relative to a user's current timezone (C#). For example, say a user is on the west coast (pacific time) where it is 8:00pm. They connect to a service that is hosted in the midwest (central time) where it is 10:00pm. If the user were to ask the server for the current time, the server should respond, "8:00pm" for the user.

My thought is that the client application (C#) will pass information to the service about its current timezone or UTC offset. Java will then create/format all dates using that timezone.

However, I am having trouble finding a good way to pass C# `System.TimeZone` information in a way where Java can create and use a `java.util.TimeZone` object. I can get the UTC offset from C# but not a three digit timezone code. In Java I can create a TimeZone from a three digit code but can't find a way to create one from a UTC offset. From everything I've seen in Java, TimeZones are created with a code ("PST") or country/region ("America/Los_Angeles"), and I don't believe there is a clear way to get the timezone in this format in C#.

How might this be accomplished?

Comment: Can you communicate with UTC and format on the client?

Comment: Unfortunately no. In this scenario, the view for the client is being generated/rendered on the server.

Answer (score 0):

## Work In UTC

As the comment suggested, usually the best way to go is to work your business logic in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Adjust into a local time zone only for presentation when expected by a user.

So your Java backend should be returning a UTC date-time value. Usually the best way to do that is to serialize the date-time value as a string in the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Then let the client app handle the presentation by generating a string representation of the date-time value adjusted into a particular time zone.

See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2532729/642706) about best practices for date-time work.

But somehow this is not feasible in the context of this Question. So the client app needs to communicate to the backend the desired/expected time zone.

## Time Zone

Avoid the 3-4 letter codes such as `EST` or `IST`. These codes are neither standardized nor unique. Furthermore they invoke Daylight Saving Time in a confusing way.

Instead use [official time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). These are mostly in the format of "continent", slash, and "region/city" in English, such as `America/Montreal` or `Asia/Kolkata`.

## .Net Fails To Support Proper Time Zone Naming

Unfortunately, it looks like the .Net team did not know about proper time zone naming.

The `System.TimeZone` class offers properties such a [`StandardName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.standardname(v=vs.110).aspx). But the examples in the [`System.TimeZone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone(v=vs.110).aspx) doc show "Pacific Standard Time" rather than a proper name such as "America/Los_Angeles".

## Noda Time

My first suggestion is to consider using the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project, an alternative date and time API for .NET. It was inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library in Java, which in turn inspired the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

Looks like Noda Time has support for proper time zones. Rather than use `System.TimeZone`, use Noda Time to obtain the time zone information.

## Roll Your Own Mapping

If Noda Time is not an option, then I might look to see if my users are all in a few time zones. If so, I would make my own mapping of such as "Pacific Daylight Time" returned by C# the standard name for a time zone being the proper name "America/Los_Angeles".